# Saving a database instance/connection per user ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I've been wondering if it is efficient to save a database instance per user to prevent creating an instance whenever the user reconnects. 
For example a user wants to use a search mechanism, so he sends a request to the server, which creates a new database per request. But is there a way to save it just once until the user decides to quit by closing the tab or browser... 
It sounds session specific, but it appears using session might be a bad idea.
I thought some would have asked this before, but couldn't find an answer. 
So should I leave it as it is, save the instance (or does the server do that for me anyways).. or should I manually do it myself? And how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave it as it is. Most (if not all) ADO.NET drivers uses connection pooling. It means that the connections aren't really closed when you invoke `Connection.Close()`. They are just returned to the pool.

Comment: ohai. 
Ok that's fine then. What if I wanted to save a result set from the database.. but still wanted to use the result set for later parsing.. is it better to save the result set or should I run the query again? The latter seems slow in comparison.. although the difference might just be a ms or secs

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization to me. Don't do anything unless it's proven that it's required. Most optimizations leads to less readable code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad.. I was worried about running the query to get the result set and parse that result set for what the user wants.